# How to return a value form Python CGI script

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, cgi

I am writing a CGI script in python to hash the content of a JSON file. And I have to get the hashed value in an HTML page. Hashing the JSON file content has been successfully executed. But I am stuck with returning the hash value.

CGI:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
from hashlib import sha256
from collections import OrderedDict

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get filename here.
fileitem = form['filename']
content = fileitem.value
cert_json = json.loads(content, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
det = json.dumps(cert_json)
hashed = sha256(det.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:

   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   open('/tmp/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())

   message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'

else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html>
<body>
   <p>%s</p>
   <p>hash:%s<p>
</body>
</html>
""" % (message,hashed)
```

The hash value is now stored in variable named "hashed". Is it possible to pass this variable to another page ?

Comment: You'd have to put it in a form input - could be hidden - and post it to the next page. Or store it in a cookie. But really you should use a real framework that can manage these sort of things for you.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I solved it using "iframe"